# Is it a problem to correlate X with changes in Y caused by X and Z?

Tags: correlation, confounding

Imagine you have three variables: *X*, *Y*, and *Z*. *X* and *Z* are both separate causes of *Y*.

You want to know if changes in *Y* caused by *Z* correlate with X. So, you manipulate *Z* to cause changes in *Y*. Let's call the observed changes *C*.

When you manipulated *Z*, you also unknowingly manipulated *X*. So, *C* contains effects from both *X* and *Z*, even though you think it only has an effect from *Z*.

Now, you correlate *C* with *X* and find a strong correlation of, say, 0.9. So, you conclude that changes in *Y* caused by *Z* correlate with *X* with a coefficient of 0.9. But remember that your measure of changes in *Y* caused by *Z*, *C*, also contains an effect from *X*. Does this make your correlation coefficient of 0.9 misleading? Would the coefficient be lower if *C* contained only an effect from *Z*?

Answer (score 1):

**Does this make your correlation coefficient of 0.9 misleading? Would the coefficient be lower if C contained only an effect from Z?**

Short answer: Yes and yes. Although changes in X won't **necessarily** distort the correlation coefficient, it certainly **might** happen.

There's a famous example from WW2. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias#:%7E:text=Survivorship%20bias%20or%20survival%20bias,conclusions%20because%20of%20incomplete%20data.):

"During World War II, the statistician Abraham Wald took survivorship bias into his calculations when considering how to minimize bomber losses to enemy fire.[17] The Statistical Research Group (SRG) at Columbia University, which Wald was a part of, examined the damage done to aircraft that had returned from missions and recommended adding armor to the areas that showed the least damage.[18][19][20] The bullet holes in the returning aircraft represented areas where a bomber could take damage and still fly well enough to return safely to base. Therefore, Wald proposed that the Navy reinforce areas where the returning aircraft were unscathed,[17]: 88  inferring that planes hit in those areas were the ones most likely to be lost. His work is considered seminal in the then nascent discipline of operational research.[21]"

In your framework:

Y - Safely returning home (binary variable).

Z - Bombing Japan (binary variable).

X - A hit in less dangerous areas. Let's say wings.

C - will be the measured effect of Z on Y **only for the planes that flew back**. Since Y is a binary variable, C is also a binary variable with a single value of 1. We can't correlate hits in the wings with planes that didn't return.

We want to know the likelihood of airplanes sent to bombing Japan (Z) to fly back to their home bases (Y). In the case you brought we'd like to measure the correlation between Z and Y.

In the story, they found that planes that returned home were frequently hit in the wings. C had a high correlation coefficient with X. The research team concluded that whether an airplane returns from bombing Japan correlates with hits in the wings ("changes in Y caused by Z correlate with X with a coefficient of 0.9"). Was the coefficient misleading? Yes. Would the coefficient be lower if they had measured the correlation between airplanes' survival and bombing Japan? Yes.

Note: You didn't specify if you're interested in Pearson correlation or other sorts of correlation coefficient. If you find the binary variables problematic you can replace them with a continuous metric for airplane's condition or something. It doesn't really make a difference.